# How can I get first top 4 highest values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I wanted to find top 5 student details who has highest no of attendance in  a class . In order to get I have used following Query. But, the problem is if the students has `attendance_count` like `7 9 12 15 1 10`, though it should return `9 10 12 15`,  it returns `9 7 15 12` `(attendance_count)` student details. How can I solve the problem ?

```
$students = DB::table('students')                
            ->select('students.*')   
            ->orderBy('students.attendance_count', 'desc') 
            ->limit(4)             
            ->where('students.status','=','1') 
            ->get();
```

Comment: Your database column is a varchar maybe? Change it to an integer.

Comment: do you save it as an integer? or maybe you created a var_char field. if you have a space character somewhere it'll mess the ordering.

Comment: Show us the migration.

Comment: Thanks @Daan solved it ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve numeric conversion like this

```
->orderBy('students.attendance_count+0', 'desc')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that column type for `students.attendance_count` in **Integer** and write the query like this

```
$students = DB::table('students')                
            ->select('students.*')              
            ->where('students.status','=','1') 
            ->orderBy('students.attendance_count', 'desc') 
            ->limit(4)  
            ->get();
```

Its good to write `orderBy` and `limit` after `where` condition.

Answer (score -1):

The order by should be used after the where clause and before the limit clause which will solve your issue

```
select student.*
from students
where status=1
order by attendence desc
limit 4;
```

Comment: Limit is already present.But once you have ordered it then only you should limit it if you limit before that it will fetch the first 4 rows of the table and not the 4 rows with the maximum attendance ,hope you got my point

Comment: Yes. OP is using laravel query bullder and it will generate the query as it needed to be. The issue is with the data type.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know this